# How to change button after onclick to loading in android

Tags: android, android-button

How can we change the button text and gif loading image on button click till we didn't get the server response in android.

please see the image:

[image]

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Add a `ProgressDialog` that is `GONE` initially becomes `VISIBLE` while server is working and is `GONE` again on completion

Comment: how we will add the gif image on ProgressDialoag?

Comment: do you want to show a custom `ProgressDialog`? If so not sure but you will probably need to create your own animation or `Handler` that changes the images on short time intervals

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of what your asking, it's bare bone but it will get you started:

[ProgressBar](https://github.com/SundeepK/ProgressButton)

At the moment, when the user clicks the button, it will display the drawable (and animate) for you but you will have to dismiss the loading animation manually once you've finished with your background task via:

```
_progressButton.stopLoadingAnimation();
```

This will dismiss any animation for you and display any previous text that was there. The only thing missing it that there is no text whilst the animation is in progress, but I think you can hack something together for that. I plan on extending this a little further so that it will allow you to call something like `_progressButton.setProgress(10)` and then set the percentage that is done. I may even make it thread safe.

You should also be able to style it exactly how you have shown in your screenshot.

To use the code, simply download the project, there's sample code there that is pretty much self explanatory.